# Identifying the number of small flowers in a Photo

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, background-color, image-segmentation

I am trying to write a program that can identify the number of flower buds on a blueberry tree. The steps I have taken so far are:

1. reduce glare
2. adjust contrast
3. threshold using red color band
4. filter out smaller and larger blobs
5. count and try to identify which remaining blobs are important using regionprops

I have developed code for steps 4-5 however it is not very effective with the results from steps 1-3, not all the flowers can be seen and because many leaves are the same color they can drown out the flowers in the image.

As you can see in this image, the flowers are small and read. [image]

[image]

Comment: Given that my flower recognition skills can only differentiate *"rose"* and *"not rose"*, could you add a second picture with circles around the bits you want detected please?

Comment: I would try to train a CNN.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for you comment, I have added another photo with circles around the roses.

Comment: @FiReTiTi thanks, Im not sure what a CNN is, but I will look into it. I assume you mean by selecting the flowers and having a code learn what they looks like?

Comment: Indeed, that's it. CNN means Convolutional Neural Network, and I use the library Keras to implement it.

Comment: @FiReTiTi I think keras is a little over my head, can you suggest anything more i could do with my exisiting code in matlab?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Any thoughts? thanks

Comment: I don't use MatLab, but it seems that there are many libraries available, but most of them seem to be not optimized for GPUs, so much slower. However, Keras is very easy to install and to use, making the development much easier.